# Visual Studio 2017 C++ Console not outputting everything

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I was following a video on YouTube that was about hash tables, and while testing some output I realized that my console was skipping quite a few lines.

So my hash table originally was of size 10. When I run the program, everything shows up properly. But when I up the size to 20, my console skips the first 3 indices. I don't know if the problem is with my code, or Visual Studio, but I was hoping someone here would know.

This is a picture of the console output with size 20:

[image]

Size 10:

[image]

```
Hash::Hash() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
        HashTable[i] = new item;
        HashTable[i]->name = "empty";
        HashTable[i]->drink = "empty";
        HashTable[i]->next = NULL;
    }
}

int Hash::hashFunction(std::string key) {
    int hash = 0;
    int index;

    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        hash = (hash + (int)key[i]) * 17;
    }

    index = hash % tableSize;

    return index;
}

void Hash::addItem(std::string name, std::string drink) {
    int index = hashFunction(name);

    if (HashTable[index]->name == "empty") {
        HashTable[index]->name = name;
        HashTable[index]->drink = drink;
    }
    else {
        item* ptr = HashTable[index];
        item* n = new item;
        n->name = name;
        n->drink = drink;
        n->next = NULL;
        while (ptr->next != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = n;
    }
}

int Hash::numItemsIndex(int index){
    int count = 0;

    if (HashTable[index]->name == "empty")
        return count; //0
    else {
        count++;
        item* ptr = HashTable[index];
        while (ptr->next != NULL) {
            count++;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

void Hash::printTable(){
    int number;

    for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
        number = numItemsIndex(i);
        cout << "-------------------------\n";
        cout << "Index = " << i << endl;
        cout << HashTable[i]->name << endl;
        cout << HashTable[i]->drink << endl;
        cout << "# of items = " << number << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }   
}

void Hash::printItemsInIndex(int index){
    item* Ptr = HashTable[index];

    if (Ptr->name == "empty")
        cout << "Index " << index << " is empty. \n";
    else {
        cout << "Index " << index << " contains the following items: \n";
        while (Ptr != NULL) {
            cout << "-------------------------\n";
            cout << Ptr->name << endl;
            cout << Ptr->drink << endl;
            cout << "-------------------------\n";
            Ptr = Ptr->next;
        }
    }

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Hash Hashy; //create of tablesize 10 and initialize
                // all with items -> empty, empty, NUll.

    Hashy.addItem("Paul", "Locha");
    Hashy.addItem("Kim", "Iced Mocha");
    Hashy.addItem("Emma", "Strawberry Smoothie");
    Hashy.addItem("Annie", "Hot Chocolate");
    Hashy.addItem("Sarah", "Passion Tea");
    Hashy.addItem("Pepper", "Caramel Mocha");
    Hashy.addItem("Mike", "Chai Tea");
    Hashy.addItem("Steve", "Apple Cider");
    Hashy.addItem("Bill", "Root Beer");
    Hashy.addItem("Marie", "Skinny Latte");
    Hashy.addItem("Susan", "Water");
    Hashy.addItem("Joe", "Green Tea");

    Hashy.printTable();
    //Hashy.printItemsInIndex(8);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

There are some things in the output section, but I don't know what they mean:

```
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Rohan Vidyarthi\Desktop\LetsHash\Debug\LetsHash.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WRusr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LetsHash.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0xbc8 has exited with code 252968960 (0xf140000).
The thread 0x1700 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x19bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1b70 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3484] LetsHash.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: That's normal output to see in the debugger and has nothing to do with your program. You haven't shown enough code for anyone to do anything but guess at your problem. Pictures of your output aren't necessary or helpful, but the code that generates that output is.

Comment: It is a problem with your code. You haven't posted all of it so it is impossible to say where the error exactly is.  Please read about [mcve]. Also read about [debugging](https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/) your code and give it a try.

Comment: Your second picture shows a scroll bar. No one has any idea what it hidws. Please don't post pictures of text terminals, they are mostly useless. Post actual text of your program output instead (all of it, not just what fits in your window).

Comment: `Cannot find or open the PDB file.` just means that you don't have debug symbols for the system DLLs. Not a problem unless you want to debug those.

Answer (score 0):

Your hash function does not produce a unique number for each string, therefore some of the indices will be duplicate. You can see this if you print out the index for each string:

```
Paul, 0 
Kim, 3
Emma, 6 
Annie, 7
Sarah, 1
Pepper, 2 
Mike, 2 
Steve, 9
Bill, 9
Marie, 0 
Susan, 6 
Joe, 8
```

You will need a much larger range for the hash values to avoid hash collisions. 0..9 is too small range and it will almost generate a collision with your current approach.

Comment: It sounds like 0-9 worked, but 0-19 didn't, which seems odd. They shouldn't need to be unique since that possibility seems to be accounted for by keeping a list in case of collision. It's entirely possible there's a bug though, but without inventing the missing code it can't really be debugged. One easy way to debug something like this is to have the hash function always return 0 to force everything to collide and how the code handles that.

Answer (score -3):

The error are due to you dont have symbol files for ntdll and all other. What you can do to avoid this error are :- There are multiple options you can have.

Download symbol package provided by microsoft. This will download PDB for all system libraries. Extract it to "c:\symbolcache"
Set symbol path to SRVc:\symbolcachehttp://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols. In this case this will download PDB files into "c:\symbolcache" if not present.
Then you have to set "c:\symbolcache" as your symbol file path into whatever crash dump analysis tool you are using.

For the error can you share the code how are you calling the hash.